# How to make Boostrap mobile hambuger button cover the whole screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

When viewing a website as a mobile site, is there a way that when you click on the hamburger button, the `nav` menu covers the whole screen.

Currently, pressing the hamburger button exposes the `nav` menu about 50%

Answer (score 0):

You can overload bootstrap classes. Since you have not given any code what you can do is find out what class in your bootstrap theme makes up the nav menu. Then overlaod it. By overload I mean create a css file and create a class with the exact same name and change the elements of that class that you want. Something like this.

```
.theClassYouWantToChange { make your changes here height: 100% maybe }
```

Then just make sure your a linking to the new style sheet along with your bootstrap template.